# reset position after jquery hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

I have this hover function for animating my imgs which works but after words when you re-size the window the images do not re-align with the width of the window, before the hover event the images will re-align, how do I reset the images after hover event show the images can be re-sized with the window?

```
$('.gallery img').hover(function(){
        $('.gallery img').each(function(){
            $(this).css({'top': $(this).offset().top, 'left': $(this).offset().left});
        });
        $('.gallery img').css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': 1});
        $(this).css('z-index', 10);
        $(this).animate({
            width: "+=14",
            height: "+=14",
            left: "-=7",
            bottom: "-=7"
        });
    }, function(){
        $(this).css('z-index', 1);
        $(this).animate({
            width: "-=14",
            height: "-=14",
            left: "+=7",
            bottom: "+=7"
        });
    });
```

Comment: When you use `hover`, once you set a CSS value, until you change it (or reload the page), it's going to save that value. You can use `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` as an aid.

Answer (score 1):

You have supplied 2 functions for the `hover()`.

E.g. `.hover(function(){},function(){})`

The first one is when the mouse enters, and the second one is when the mouse leaves.

I suspect the culprit is:

```
.css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index': 1});
```

In the second function, try setting `position: static`. I would say after the animation.